# Can anybody make this code shorter using a loop?

Tags: java, loops, weekday

Just a short program that figures out what day it will be in an amount of days the user inputs. I have it starting at DAY 6 which is Saturday. Is there a way I can shorter the code using a loop?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Week{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int days[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
        String dayNames[] = {"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday",
                "Saturday", "Sunday"};
        int numdays;

        System.out.println("Enter how many days from now: ");
        numdays = input.nextInt();

        numdays = (6 + numdays) % 7;

        if(numdays == 0){
            System.out.println(dayNames[6]);
        }
        else if(numdays == 1 ){
            System.out.println(dayNames[0]);
        }
        else if(numdays == 2){
            System.out.println(dayNames[1]);
        }
        else if(numdays == 3){
            System.out.println(dayNames[2]);
        }
        else if(numdays == 4){
            System.out.println(dayNames[3]);
        }
        else if(numdays == 5){
            System.out.println(dayNames[4]);
        }
        else if(numdays == 6){
            System.out.println(dayNames[5]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at your if statements. Can you spot a pattern?

Comment: @NilsH Exactly, do some arithmetic in your print statement.

Comment: `int days[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};`  When did the 8 day week start?  I Hope it means 3 days of weekend.. You could have the extra day after Sunday & call it Funday.  :)

Answer (score 3):

The following section:

```
if(numdays == 0){
    System.out.println(dayNames[6]);
}
else if(numdays == 1 ){
    System.out.println(dayNames[0]);
}
else if(numdays == 2){
    System.out.println(dayNames[1]);
}
else if(numdays == 3){
    System.out.println(dayNames[2]);
}
else if(numdays == 4){
    System.out.println(dayNames[3]);
}
else if(numdays == 5){
    System.out.println(dayNames[4]);
}
else if(numdays == 6){
    System.out.println(dayNames[5]);
}
```

... is trivially replaced with:

```
System.out.println(dayNames[(numdays + 6) % 7)]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Start with sunday:

```
String dayNames[] = {"Sunday", "Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday",
            "Saturday"};
```

Replace the big if/else with:

```
System.out.println(dayNames[numdays]);
```

Comment: That has also the virtue of beginning the array with the first day of the week :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `switch` case instead of multiple if statements

like

```
switch(numdays) {
  case 1:  ....  break;
  case 2: ..... break;
.....
}
```

or

```
String dayNames[] = {"Sunday", "Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday",
  "Friday","Saturday"};
```

then  you can  specify index directly

```
System.out.println(dayNames[numdays]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(numdays=0;numdays<=6;numdays++){
System.out.println(dayNames[(numdays + 6) % 7)]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a loop

```
String dayNames[] = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday",
                "Sunday" };
int i  = (5 + numdays) % 7;
System.out.println(dayNames[i]);
```